# Store the contents of a curl command which is executed from within a python script

Tags: python, json, curl

When I execute this [say filename as curl.py and execute by python curl.py]

```
import subprocess
import json
subprocess.call([
        'curl',
        '--digest',
        '--user',
        'user:pass',
        'https://url'],
        )
```

The output is a JSON file in my case.
I see the output on my terminal, but I want it to be stored in an object in the same python file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is using `curl` a requirement? There are Python libraries to do the same thing.

Comment: Yep, If you think of any alternative which returns the same, Kindly do suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, here's an alternative without curl. I am using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) here (`pip install requests`):

```
import requests
url = 'http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/pass'
r = requests.get(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'))
print(r.json())  # no need to unpack JSON manually!
```

Comment: Please do upvote my question that other people may see this post and get their answer !